# next-auth + fb provider, only returns profile pic and name

Tags: node.js, facebook, authentication, next.js, next-auth

Hello currently I have next_auth + fb provider in my app. I need to add user to database after users signin through fb, for this I also need either email or mobile num. Currently, the user session only returns the pic and user name.

```
 FacebookProvider({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      scope: 'email,user_friends,user_gender,user_age_range,user_phone_number'
    })
```

"next": "13.2.4",
"next-auth": "^4.20.1",

Comment: user_phone_number - are you sure there is any permission for the phone number? that would be new and i highly doubt that they added it. either way, you may need to get your app scopes reviewed before they work for regular users.

Comment: Normal 3rd-party apps can't get access to the user's mobile number, that is something only a few specific partners like Uber are able to do.